# installing Vcpkg to manage c/c++ libraries on windows (Vs Code)

Tags: visual-studio-code, vcpkg, symbolicc++

when trying to install vcpkg to manage and install c/c++ libraries on windows 10, this error keeps showing up :
PS C:\librairies\vcpkg> .\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat
Downloading https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg-tool/releases/download/2021-05-05-9f849c4c43e50d1b16186ae76681c27b0c1be9d9/vcpkg.exe -> C:\librairies\vcpkg\vcpkg.exe
Done.

### Telemetry

vcpkg collects usage data in order to help us improve your experience.
The data collected by Microsoft is anonymous.
You can opt-out of telemetry by re-running the bootstrap-vcpkg script with -disableMetrics,
passing --disable-metrics to vcpkg on the command line,
or by setting the VCPKG_DISABLE_METRICS environment variable.

Answer (score 0):

In Vscode PS on Win11 x64, re-run like this:

```
.\vcpkg\bootstrap-vcpkg.bat -disableMetrics
```

With output as follows:

Downloading https://github.com/microsoft/vcpkg-tool/releases/download/2022-03-09/vcpkg.exe -> C:\vcpkg\vcpkg.exe... done.
Validating signature... done.